# How can I open file from dir and save file to new dir?

Tags: python, tkinter

how can i open file and save file to new dir?

here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Pilih PDF", "*.pdf"), ("Semua File", ".*")))
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)
    browsebutton = Button(root, text="Pilih PDF", command=browsefunc)
    browsebutton.pack()
    pathlabel = Label(root)

def savefunc():
   filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initaldir="/", filetypes=(("PDF","*.pdf"),("Semua File", ".*")))
   pathlabel.config(text=filename)
   savebutton = Button(root, text="PDF", command=savefunc)
   savebutton.pack()
   pathlabel = Label(root)
   pathlabel.pack()

mainloop()
```

i can't save the file

Comment: Can you provide an error log?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: i can open the file, but when i save i got this error
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-initaldir": must be -confirmoverwrite, -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -parent, -title, or -typevariable
@ShiheZhang

Comment: @CodeID:  which error?

Comment: here @cdarke
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-initaldir": must be -confirmoverwrite, -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -parent, -title, or -typevariable

Comment: You misspelled `initialdir` as `initaldir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shutil.copy(src, dst)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) will work

```
import shutil

shutil.copy('dir1/file.txt', 'dir2/file_copy.txt')
```

Comment: can it be used for tkinter?

Comment: `shutil` is a standard library module. Opening a file and saving it in a new location is generally called copying, and shutil.copy provides that functionality.